# C++ - got 'error C2064' when using <list> template

Tags: c++, list, mergesort

I'm implementing the **MERGE SORT** algorithm. I use std::list < int > as my list of input numbers. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <list>

void MergeSort(list<int> _list)
{
    if (_list.size() > 1)
    {
        list<int> left;
        list<int> right;
        int mid = (0+_list.size())/2;
        list<int>::iterator i = _list.begin();
        for (int j = 0; j<mid; j++) ++i;
        left.assign(_list.begin(),++i);
        right.assign(i, _list.end());
        MergeSort(left);
        MergeSort(right);
        _list.merge(left,right);
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    list<int> myList;
    myList.push_front(38);
    myList.push_back(27);
    myList.push_back(43);
    myList.push_back(3);
    myList.push_back(9);
    myList.push_back(82);
    myList.push_back(10);
    cout << "Before sorting:\n";
    list<int>::iterator i;
    for(i=myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); ++i) cout << *i << " ";
    // Merge Sort Function
    MergeSort(myList);
    //
    cout << "\nAfter sorting:\n";
    for(i=myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); ++i) 
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But I builded this source file on Visual Studio 2012 and got this error: **error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments (file)c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility   (line)595**
This is the first time i've dealed with this error and I have no idea how to fix it... Hope you guys can help me with this, thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: Unrelated: In case you weren't aware, [`std::list<T>::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) does this for you. Related: Your in for a rude surprise regarding your by-value parameter being passed to `MergeSort`, as it will do nothing to the actual `myList` container in `main()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `list<int>::merge` correctly in the expression `_list.merge(left, right);`
check the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/) for merge function. There you can also find an example on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm such a dumb didnt notice that. No I have my problem fixed :)